# Bootstrap Table adjustment

Tags: html, jsp, bootstrap-4

Here is my UI
[image]

Here is my code

```
<div class="container">  
   <table id="headerTable" class="table table-bordered ">
     <thead class="thead-default">
       <tr>
        <th colspan="2">電文Header</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Filler1</th>
            <td><input id="123" type="text" class="input-sm"></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <th>MessageType</th>
            <td><input id="123" type="text" class="input-sm"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>MessageLength</th>
            <td><input id="123" type="text" class="input-sm"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How do I adjust the  to make it smaller like following?
[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container"> 
<table id="headerTable" class="table table-bordered ">
    <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">電文Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1">Filler1</th>
            <td class="col-sm-11"> 
                <input id="123" type="text" class="input-sm">
            </td>
        </tr>             
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1">MessageType</th>
            <td class="col-sm-11"> 
                <input type="text" class="input-sm">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-1">MessageLength</th>
            <td class="col-sm-11"> 
                <input type="text" class="input-sm">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just put in the [Bootstrap Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) class so that `<th>` and `<td>` element would not be too wide.
See https://www.bootply.com/BLINHddRZV for output.

Edit: Did not see it is using bootstrap4. Please check [this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23117) issue and the reply from mdo. Apparently, the grid class is no longer supported for table.

Comment: I put class="col-md-2" in <td> part,  so the left side is narrower than right side. thank you

Comment: @user2447944 Just updated my code. <td> should be taking up 10 units while <th> being up 2 units wide. This should be a better answer than my original one.

Comment: I updated the code as you recommended. <th class="col-sm-2">MessageType</th> is wider than <td class="col-sm-10">.    what I want is opposite way...

Comment: please the following answer I added

Comment: @Bmegod It would be great to update your code by editing the question to avoid confusion. The problem I am worrying is that the correct code (that most browsers seem to accept) is not working in your environment. Therefore, there could be issue when you use the "somehow working" code.

Comment: @Bmegod Perhaps you could provide us some more information about your environment. Looks like you are setting up an HTML form for a trade (交易). What client/browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149459/discussion-between-tim1234-and-bmegod).

Comment: sorry, I am new to the Stackoverflow forum, yes, I will update the code by editing the question.

Comment: the client side browser is Chorme